# How to assign a foreign key to another table while submitting one form in Laravel Vue?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have two different tables:

Table one (parties):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->string('ic_passport');
        $table->string('nationality');
        $table->string('income_tax_no');
        $table->string('income_Tax_filing_branch');
        $table->string('phone_no');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Table two(corraddresses)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('corraddresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('address_1');
        $table->string('address_2');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('poscode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

i am trying to assign the primary key from table one (parties) to table two (corraddresses) as foreign key

so as far as i know i need to add the following to table two(corraddresses):

```
$table->unsignedInteger('corraddresses_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('corraddresses_id')
   ->references('id')
   ->on('corraddresses')
   ->onDelete('cascade');
```

"Correct me if i am wrong"

in the case above do i need to modify the models?

Party model:

```
class Party extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['full_name','ic_passport','nationality','income_tax_no',
'income_Tax_filing_branch','phone_no','email'];
}
```

Corraddress Model:

```
class Corraddress extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['address_1','address_2','city','poscode'];
}
```

after that here is my main question:

i am submitting one from that will save data to table one (parties) and table two (corraddresses) as follow:

```
data() {
return {
full_name: '',
ic_passport: '',
nationality: '',
income_tax_no: '',
income_Tax_filing_branch: '',
phone_no: '',
email: '',
address_1: '',
address_2: '',
city: '',
poscode: '',
};
},
methods: {
addNewPost(){
            axios.post('/api/auth/party',{
                full_name: this.full_name,
                ic_passport: this.ic_passport,
                nationality: this.nationality,
                income_tax_no: this.income_tax_no,
                income_Tax_filing_branch: this.income_Tax_filing_branch,
                phone_no: this.phone_no,
                email: this.email,
            })
            axios.post('/api/auth/corraddress',{
                address_1: this.address_1,
                address_2: this.address_2,
                city: this.city,
                poscode: this.poscode,
            })
            .then((response)=>{
                this.$router.push({name:"database-management"})
            $('#success').html(response.data.message)
            })
},
},
```

in the case above will it affect the foreign key? will be here any modification for it to assign the foreign key? or it just need to be done in migration and model? do i need to provide the controllers as well to this post?

Note: i'm using Laravel 8 with vue 2

UPDATE:

CorraddressController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $corraddress = Corraddress::create($request->post());
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Corraddress Created Successfully!!',
        'corraddress'=>$corraddress
    ]);
}
```

PartyController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $party = Party::create($request->post());
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Party Created Successfully!!',
        'party'=>$party
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please add your controllers as that is where all the logic is to be happening, but from the javascript side of things it doesnt seem like there is an obvious relation between the party and address

Comment: i have added the controllers to the post

Comment: From the code you have shown so far `corraddresses_id` is always null